# Junit - Multiple @Before vs. one @Before split up into methods

Tags: java, junit

In a unit test, I need to perform a quite complex setup (this may be a code smell but this is not what this question is about :-)). What I'm interested in is if it is better to have multiple `@Before` methods performing the setup or just one, which calls helper methods to perform the initialization.

E.g.

```
@Before
public void setUpClientStub() {

}

@Before
public void setUpObjectUnderTest() {

}
```

vs.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    setUpClientStub();
    setUpObjectUnderTest();
}
```

Comment: what about a baseclass? otherwise I dont see any point against methods...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As has been said in other responses, the order in which JUnit finds methods is not guaranteed, so the execution order of `@Before` methods can't be guaranteed. The same is true of `@Rule`, it suffers from the same lack of guarantee. If this will always be the same code, then there isn't any point in splitting into two methods.

If you do have two methods, and more importantly, if you wish to use them from multiple places, then you can combine rules using a [RuleChain](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules/RuleChain.java), which was introduced in 4.10. This allows the specific ordering of rules, such as:

```
public static class UseRuleChain {
  @Rule
  public TestRule chain= RuleChain
               .outerRule(new LoggingRule("outer rule"))
               .around(new LoggingRule("middle rule"))
               .around(new LoggingRule("inner rule"));

  @Test
  public void example() {
      assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```

This produces:

```
starting outer rule
starting middle rule
starting inner rule
finished inner rule
finished middle rule
finished outer rule
```

So you can either upgrade to 4.10 or just steal the class.

In your case, you could define two rules, one for client setup and one for object, and combine them in a `RuleChain`. Using [ExternalResource](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ExternalResource.html).

```
public static class UsesExternalResource {
  private TestRule clientRule = new ExternalResource() {
      @Override
      protected void before() throws Throwable {
        setupClientCode();
      };

      @Override
      protected void after() {
        tearDownClientCode()
    };
  };

  @Rule public TestRule chain = RuleChain
                   .outerRule(clientRule)
                   .around(objectRule);
}
```

So you'll have the following execution order:

```
clientRule.before()
objectRule.before()
the test
objectRule.after()
clientRule.after()
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but in terms of readability I would chose @hvgotcodes suggestion.

Comment: Even if the methods are not meant to be reused, it can make sense to have them as separate methods in order to give them meaningful names, as opposed to adding comments in the method.

Answer (score 8):

I would do the latter.  AFAIK, there is no way to guarantee order of @Before annotated setup methods.

Answer (score 5):

Note that there are no guarantees about the order in which `@Before` annotated methods are invoked. If there are some dependencies between them (e.g. one method must be called before the other), you *must* use the latter form.

Otherwise this is a matter of preference, just keep them in a single place so it is easy to spot them.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it makes much of a difference, but I personally prefer the second one (the order Before methods are executed being not defined, you'll have a better control that way).

Answer (score 2):

For me it seems using `JUnit 4.12`, the methods annotated with `@Before` get indeed sorted **deterministically** by the following characteristic:

**by reversed lexicographic order** with respect to the **method name**.

You can see this behaviour by executing this Testclass:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

/*
 * key points:
 * - multiple @Before methods get sorted by reversed lexicographic order 
 * */
public class JUnitLifecyle {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void runsOnceBeforeClassIsInited() {
        System.out.println("@BeforeClass");
    }

    public JUnitLifecyle() {
        System.out.println("Constructor");
    }

    @Before
    public void a() {
        System.out.println("@Before a");
    }

    @Before
    public void b() {
        System.out.println("@Before b");
    }

    @Before
    public void cd() {
        System.out.println("@Before cd");
    }

    @Before
    public void ca() {
        System.out.println("@Before ca");
    }

    @Before
    public void cc() {
        System.out.println("@Before cc");
    }

    @Before
    public void d() {
        System.out.println("@Before d");
    }

    @Before
    public void e() {
        System.out.println("@Before e");
    }

    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        System.out.println("@Test 1");
    }

    @Test
    public void secondTest() {
        System.out.println("@Test 2");
    }

    @After
    public void runsAfterEveryTestMethod() {
        System.out.println("@After");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void runsOnceAfterClass() {
        System.out.println("@AfterClass");
    }
}
```

I came to this conclusion after playing around with the output, while changing the method names of the methods annotated with `@Before`.

Keeping this *reversed lexicographic order* in mind you could name your methods accordingly to let `JUnit` execute your setup tasks in the right order.

Although the above approach is possible, I think you should not do this in your tests, because the Java-Annotations thing in JUnit was introduced to get away from convention-based testing.

Answer (score 0):

I declared all my @Before methods private and created a single method annotated with @Before that called all those and my tests worked. I have worked in kotlin.
Here's how you can do it:

```
private fun setUpClientStub() {
     //whatever you want to do
}

private fun setUpObjectUnderTest() {
    //whatever you want to do
}

@Before
fun setUp() {
    setUpClientStub()
    setUpObjectUnderTest()
}

@Test
fun test() {
   //your test logic
}
```

This way you can ensure that your methods are called in the right order and you can name them any way you want.